# Canonical labeling of graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, isomorphism-testing

**Definition** : Let $V$ be a linearly ordered set and $\Sigma$ an alphabet. A $\Sigma$- string on $V$ is a function $x : V \mapsto \Sigma$. The set of all $\Sigma$- strings on $V$ is defined by $\Sigma^{V}$. **Strings can be regarded as particular structures with only unary relations. Thus, for $\sigma \in Sym(V)$ the $x^{\sigma}$ satisfies $x^{\sigma}(v) = x (v^{\sigma^{-1}})$**

**Reference :**
[Canonical labeling of graphs by Laszlo babai and E.M Luks](http://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~luks/CanLabel.pdf)

I am trying to understand the definition but not getting the bolded text in the above definition.

1)  'Strings can be regarded as particular structures with only unary relations'

2) 'for $\sigma \in Sym(V)$ the $x^{\sigma}$ satisfies $x^{\sigma}(v) = x (v^{\sigma^{-1}})$'

Comment: 2) I interpret it as you have vertices (numbered), and each vertex is assigned something from the alphabet. If you permute the vertex labeling AND the assignment in the same way (vertex 2 still is assigned letter 'a'), then the map x is considered the same.

Comment: Ha, I re-read the definition four times before proceeding to the question because I didn't understand the bolded text. After that your question came as a pleasant surprise!

Comment: I read 2) as the standard way of lifting the group action on a set to an action on functions defined on that set. If we write our actions using the $\cdot$ notation, it would read: $(\sigma \cdot x) (v) = x( \sigma^{-1} \cdot v)$.